# XML-free Spring not setting up

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, config

I've run this project previously in STS but am trying to replicate it in Eclipse 4.2 to no luck. I'm running the same Spring XML-free base setup as described http://blog.codeleak.pl/2011/06/spring-31-mvc-xml-free-configuration-in.html .

I'm using maven 3 embedded in Eclipse 4.2 and an embedded tomcat 7.
When I start the project up on tomcat 7.0.12...

```
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Development\jdks\jdk1.7.0_25_x86\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Development/jdks/jdk1.7.0_25_x86/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Development/jdks/jdk1.7.0_25_x86/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Development/jdks/jdk1.7.0_25_x86/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Development\jdks\jdk1.7.0_25_x86\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Access\Advanced\Wave\Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Security Innovation\SI TSS\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Development\eclipse-4.2_x86;;.
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:inst_tdcsim_server' did not find a matching property.
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 422 ms
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 05, 2013 1:04:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 259 ms
```

No mention of mappings being registered and no URL works, just 404s.

I tried changing the context root in Eclipse and the Tomcat server xml to '/' and that dind't help either.

I tried setting debug points in the code and nothing stops.
I tried setting all logging to 'ALL' after I brought in log4j, nothing shows.
I tried creating a blatant nullpointerexception on the first line of the onStartup method and nothing.
How is this spring app not responding to anything I try to do to get a response?
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Not really much to go on.

Comment: Interestingly when I use the maven tomcat7 plugin - "mvn tomcat7:run" I get a functional server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved Eclipse not deploying the assembly correctly.

Goto properties on the project -> Deployment Assembly -> Added "/src/main/java" deployed to "WEB-INF/classes" and then it picked up my Initializer. Not sure why this wasn't there to begin with.